# How to enable email notification after a successful backup performed by Heptio Ark in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am planning to create an e-mail notification after performing a successful backup taken by Heptio Ark in Kubernetes. How can I enable this in our setup?

Comment: improved spelling

Comment: In what way does [post hooks](https://github.com/heptio/ark/blame/v0.10.1/docs/api-types/backup.md#L120) not do what you want?